# Texte fuzzy in phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I have a problem with displaying text in phonegap, i get a fuzzy text in some devices, like this image

[image]

I use jquery to set text with this code

```
$("#budgetMois").html(json[i].ROW[0].COL[0].DATA.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g," ") + " €");

$("#BA_val").html(json[i].ROW[0].COL[1].DATA.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g," ") + " €");

$("#dep").html("<font color='#d44c33'>+" + json[i].ROW[0].COL[2].DATA + "%</font>");

$("#gnature").html(id + " = ");

$("#ba").html("Budget annuel : ");

$("#dep_lab").html("<font color='#d44c33'>d&eacute;pass&eacute;</font>");
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You seem to have a random closing curly brackets after your third .html() and within your third .html() I think you have a plus sign within quotations when it should be outside.

Comment: you can be more clear? you can suggest a correct code?

Comment: I have made an edit to make your code clearer and corrected what I believe were just typos in the question.

Comment: the plus in #dep is not a typo

Comment: My mistake with that one, I see it now. Presumably the other was just a typo then. But I did remove a } as well. I don't imagine it has anything to do with your issue, but could cause problems for people attempting to answer your question.